# limiting value of the angle between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, summation, vectors, normed-spaces

Let $θ$ be the angle between the vectors $A = 
(1,1,...,1)$ and$ B = (1,2,...,n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Find the limiting value of θ as n → ∞.

For this question, I want to apply the equation for the angle between two vectors: $θ=arccos\frac{A·B}{\|A\|\|B\|}$. For A·B, I use $A·B=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k$. And for the norm of A and B, I simply use the definition to get $\|A\|=\sqrt{n}$ and $\|B\|=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2}$. But I'm stuck here. I don't know how to calculate the  limit of θ as n→ ∞ by these equations.

Comment: Well, did you compute $A\cdot B$?

Comment: your $\|B\|$ is incorrect

Comment: Ohh yeah that's a typo. I've corrected that. @Exodd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that

$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=1}^n k &= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{cases}$$

You get

$$\frac{A_n \cdot B_n}{\Vert A_n \Vert \Vert B_n \Vert}  = \frac{n(n+1)/2}{\sqrt n \sqrt{n(n+1)(2n+1)/6}} \to \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$ as $n \to \infty$ and therefore

$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$$ as $\arccos$ is continuous.